# Creating a responsive nav bar on lower width dimension without javascript

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to create a nav bar thats responsive for basic sizes, but I'm not entirely sure how to have the nav links change into a menu button which can be expanded to show the nav options.

I current have the options just stack and be centered under 769px, but what I am looking for is more along the lines of [this nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seFUW.png).

This is what I currently have:

```css
header {
    background-color: #666;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 35px;
    color: white;
}

body {
 font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6;
 margin: 0;
 min-height: 100vh;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}


h2,
h3,
a {
 color: #34495e;
}

a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
    background-color: #d3d3d3;
    border-radius: 40px;
}

.logo {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 1.45em;
}

.main-nav {
 margin-top: 5px;

}
.logo,
.main-nav a {
 padding: 10px 15px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-align: center;
 display: block;
}

.main-nav a {
 color: #34495e;
 font-size: .99em;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #718daa;
}

.header {
 padding-top: .5em;
 padding-bottom: .5em;
 border: 1px solid #a2a2a2;
 background-color: #f4f4f4;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
 -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
 border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

@media (min-width: 769px) {
 .header,
 .main-nav {
  display: flex;
 }
 .header {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
     .header{
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1150px;
 }
 }

}

@media (min-width: 1025px) {
 .header {
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
 }

}
```

```html
<nav class="header">
    <h2 class="logo">Logo</h2>
    <ul class="main-nav">
        <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Destinations</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Experiences</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Travel Guides</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">References</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: That looks like a good. So you need an element for the ≡ and next step is to work out how to toggle it. What bit are you struggling with in particular? Adding this element? Toggling the menu – showing and hiding or animating the slide down?

Comment: You could use the `:focus` pseudo selecter to determine if the button is clicked which would then display the menu adjacent to the button using the adjacent sibling selector like so: `.menu-trigger:focus + .menu { display: block }`. Just an idea. The issue is that the menu will close as soon as the button looses focus.

Comment: @Djave Sorry for the late reply. The thing I was having an issue with is how to actually make the links collapse into a ≡. I'm unsure how to tackle this as its my first time :)